# Rails Error "uninitialized constant User::Corporateprofiles"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to make a program in which when a user is created, automatically a corporateprofile is automatically created along with it. However upon trying to view the corporate profile i keep running into the below error..

NameError in CorporateprofilesController#show

```
uninitialized constant User::Corporateprofiles
```

I have read through my code over and over for spelling mistakes however no avail, also please note I am using nested routes in which each user has on corporateprofile.

Routes.rb

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :searches
    resources :corporateprofiles
  end
end
```

Corporateprofiles Controller

```
class CorporateprofilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user

  def show
    @corporateprofile = current_user.corporateprofiles.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @corporateprofile = current_user.corporateprofiles.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @corporateprofile = Corporateprofile.find(current_user.corporateprofile.id)
    if @corporateprofile.update_attributes(corporateprofile_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Something went wrong" 
      render edit_user_corporateprofiles_path
    end
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:corporateprofile).permit(:companyname, :companylogo,:companybanner,:companywebsite,:companyindustry,:companytype, :companyheadquarters,:companysize,:companyvideo,:aboutus,:city,:state,:country)
  end
end
```

Corporate Profile Model

```
class Corporateprofile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :build_profile

  has_many :searches, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :corporateprofiles, dependent: :destroy

  def build_profile
    Corporateprofile.create(user: self) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.
  end

  has_secure_password 
end
```

Have read all the similar stack overflow posts even the error checking ones however I'm still unable to figure out whats causing the error.

Any help would be so much appreciated

Comment: what is the file name where you have the model `Corporateprofile`? In Rails we name it like `CorporateProfile`.. and fie name should be then `corporate_profile.rb`. Please follow the Rails conventions to write this things..

Comment: Anyway, you should be fine when you write `has_one :corporateprofiles, dependent: :destroy` as `has_one :corporateprofile, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: aha this worked! Is this because corporateprofile is under a Has_one relationship whereas searches can be plural due to the has_many relationship?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you set up `has_one :corporateprofiles`. You used the plural of your model name, but rails expects singular. Therefor it is looking for the class `Corporateprofiles`.

First off - to fix this, change your **Naming**

It is convention to name classes `CamelCase` - so change your model to `CorporateProfile`. You will have to change your files to *corporate_profile(_controller).rb* as well.

This also makes your relations much easier to read and write.

```
class User
  has_one :corporate_profile, dependent: :destroy
  # ... other stuff
end
```

Secondly - I would suggest you improve your `after_create` **callback**. I find it much nicer to directly access `self` than calling the other model and defining `user: self`

```
def build_profile
  self.corporate_profile = CorporateProfile.create
end
```

Comment: Why do you people missing the whole point? OP has `has_one :corporate profiles`, which Rails by default will convert to model name, but that is not the actual model

Comment: he has error because than constant is not initialized, not because of other things

Comment: Thanks all for your assistance on this, TheChamp i have taken your feedback onboard and implemented your refined after_create callback.

Ultimately Arup and yourself were correct in me needing to change the pluralisation in "You used the plural of your model name, but rails expects singular". 

Problem solved everyone! Thanks for your speedy responses as well as additional learnings

Answer (score 1):

You have an error, because you broke rails naming conventions. So, for table name `corporate_profiles`:

- Model file name should be `corporate_profile.rb`.
- Model class name should be `CorporateProfile`.
- Controller class name should be `CorporateProfilesController`.
- `has_one` association name should be `corporate_profile`.

Comment: you are still incorrect. OP didn't follow the convention I agree. But the issue is as I commented. If OP follow my comment the code will be green. The error is not because he didn't use `corporate_profile`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've now updated my naming conventions to the appropriate! Apologies, i'm still very new to rails and currently learning.

Currently Arup Rakshit's answer fixed my problems perfectly!